Why is the output of this code incorrect？
Normally, the output should always be 200.But the output of "totalMoney" sometimes a number less than 200. What is the issue here and how to correct it?
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <set>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

class Account {
public:
  Account(string name, double money): mName(name), mMoney(money) {};

public:
  void changeMoney(double amount) {
    unique_lock lock(mMoneyLock);
    mConditionVar.wait(lock, [this, amount] {
      return mMoney + amount > 0;
    });
    mMoney += amount;
    mConditionVar.notify_all();
  }

  string getName() {
    return mName;
  }

  double getMoney() {
    return mMoney;
  }

private:
  string mName;
  double mMoney;
  mutex mMoneyLock;
  condition_variable mConditionVar;
};

class Bank {
public:
  void addAccount(Account* account) {
    mAccounts.insert(account);
  }

  void transferMoney(Account* accountA, Account* accountB, double amount) {
    accountA->changeMoney(-amount);
    accountB->changeMoney(amount);
  }

  double totalMoney() const {
    double sum = 0;
    for (auto a : mAccounts) {
      sum += a->getMoney();
    }
    return sum;
  }

private:
  set<Account*> mAccounts;
};

mutex sCoutLock;
void randomTransfer(Bank* bank, Account* accountA, Account* accountB) {
  while(true) {
    double randomMoney = ((double)rand() / RAND_MAX) * 100;
    {
      lock_guard guard(sCoutLock);
      cout << "Try to Transfer " << randomMoney
           << " from " << accountA->getName() << "(" << accountA->getMoney()
           << ") to " << accountB->getName() << "(" << accountB->getMoney()
           << "), Bank totalMoney: " << bank->totalMoney() << endl;
    }
    bank->transferMoney(accountA, accountB, randomMoney);
  }
}

int main() {
  Account a("Paul", 100);
  Account b("Moira", 100);

  Bank aBank;
  aBank.addAccount(&a);
  aBank.addAccount(&b);

  thread t1(randomTransfer, &aBank, &a, &b);
  thread t2(randomTransfer, &aBank, &b, &a);

  t1.join();
  t2.join();

  return 0;
}

Here is the output in my machine:
0x16be37000Try to Transfer 51.0047 from Moira(135.637) to Paul(64.363), Bank totalMoney: 200
0x16bdab000Try to Transfer 36.512 from Paul(3.19498) to Moira(196.805), Bank totalMoney: 148.995
0x16bdab000Try to Transfer 97.5377 from Paul(17.6877) to Moira(182.312), Bank totalMoney: 200
0x16be37000Try to Transfer 57.5533 from Moira(182.312) to Paul(17.6877), Bank totalMoney: 200
0x16be37000Try to Transfer 15.3912 from Moira(124.759) to Paul(75.2409), Bank totalMoney: 200
0x16be37000Try to Transfer 80.3468 from Moira(109.368) to Paul(90.6322), Bank totalMoney: 200
0x16be37000Try to Transfer 88.5104 from Moira(29.021) to Paul(170.979), Bank totalMoney: 200
0x16be37000Try to Transfer 6.12762 from Moira(38.0483) to Paul(161.952), Bank totalMoney: 200
0x16bdab000Try to Transfer 93.9196 from Paul(168.079) to Moira(31.9207), Bank totalMoney: 200
0x16bdab000Try to Transfer 74.2804 from Paul(74.1597) to Moira(125.84), Bank totalMoney: 200
0x16be37000Try to Transfer 86.873 from Moira(125.84) to Paul(74.1597), Bank totalMoney: 200
0x16be37000Try to Transfer 30.5068 from Moira(38.9673) to Paul(161.033), Bank totalMoney: 200
0x16be37000Try to Transfer 27.1903 from Moira(8.46051) to Paul(191.539), Bank totalMoney: 200
0x16be37000Try to Transfer 77.4606 from Moira(55.5506) to Paul(144.449), Bank totalMoney: 200
0x16bdab000Try to Transfer 86.9267 from Paul(144.449) to Moira(55.5506), Bank totalMoney: 200
0x16bdab000Try to Transfer 80.6416 from Paul(57.5226) to Moira(142.477), Bank totalMoney: 200
0x16bdab000Try to Transfer 21.181 from Paul(54.3416) to Moira(145.658), Bank totalMoney: 200
0x16bdab000Try to Transfer 88.7459 from Paul(33.1607) to Moira(166.839), Bank totalMoney: 200
0x16be37000Try to Transfer 43.7033 from Moira(166.839) to Paul(33.1607), Bank totalMoney: 200
0x16be37000Try to Transfer 52.4541 from Moira(123.136) to Paul(76.864), Bank totalMoney: 200
0x16be37000Try to Transfer 95.9126 from Moira(70.682) to Paul(129.318), Bank totalMoney: 200
0x16bdab000Try to Transfer 3.00996 from Paul(40.5721) to Moira(159.428), Bank totalMoney: 200
0x16bdab000Try to Transfer 88.4315 from Paul(37.5622) to Moira(66.5252), Bank totalMoney: 104.087
0x16be37000Try to Transfer 68.97 from Moira(66.5252) to Paul(133.475), Bank totalMoney: 200

I tried to add a mutex in the getMoney() like this:
  double getMoney() {
    lock_guard lk(mMoneyLock);
    return mMoney;
  }

still the similar output, then i try to add add mutex in the totalMoney() like this:
  double totalMoney() const {
    double sum = 0;
    lock_guard lk(mLock);
    for (auto a : mAccounts) {
      sum += a->getMoney();
    }
    return sum;
  }

I got the similar output again ,so I'm stuck...

totalMoney and transferMoney need to be protected by the same mutex.

Aside, never use floating point to count money.

A side note: see Pseudo-random number generation. It is recommended to use it instead of rand().

In addition, PRNGs are not thread-safe (at least those provided by standard libraries). Try to move rand() call into the guarded section. (Plus better switch to a C++ PRNG.)

Just an addition to @n.m.couldbeanAI's answer: The result of float-point number calculation is up to the order of numbers and operations.

Yes, money is important, and the auditors get crazy when 0.1 + 0.2 is not exactly 0.3  https://0.30000000000000004.com/   Instead, real banks will count the cents and insert a decimal point in the output.


Normally, the output should always be 200.But the output of "totalMoney" sometimes a number less than 200. What is the issue here and how to correct it?

Why the output of "totalMoney" sometimes a number less than 200 probably is that the stems from a lack of synchronization between the threads during the transfer process. The potential issue is in Bank::transferMoney method, where calling changeMoney on accountA and accountB separately.
void transferMoney(Account* accountA, Account* accountB, double amount) {
    accountA->changeMoney(-amount);
    accountB->changeMoney(amount);
}

This method releases the lock between the two operations, might resulting in inconsistencies in the total amount of money across the accounts.
void changeMoney(double amount) {
    unique_lock lock(mMoneyLock);
    mConditionVar.wait(lock, [this, amount] {
    return mMoney + amount > 0;
   });
   mMoney += amount;
   mConditionVar.notify_all();
}

What you can try to make transfer process is atomic. locking both accounts during the transfer
class Account {
public:
    Account(string name, double money): mName(name), mMoney(money) {};

public:
    void changeMoney(double amount) {
        unique_lock lock(mMoneyLock);
        mConditionVar.wait(lock, [this, amount] {
        return mMoney + amount >= 0;
        });
        mMoney += amount;
        mConditionVar.notify_all();
    }

    string getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    double getMoney() {
        // Locking
        unique_lock lock(mMoneyLock);
        return mMoney;
    }

    mutex& getMutex() {
        return mMoneyLock;
    }

private:
    string mName;
    double mMoney;
    mutex mMoneyLock;
    condition_variable mConditionVar;
};

Also try to use a std::scoped_lock to lock both accounts’ mutexes when performing the transfer.
class Bank {
public:
    void addAccount(Account* account) {
        mAccounts.insert(account);
    }

    void transferMoney(Account* accountA, Account* accountB, double amount) {
        // Lock both accounts
        scoped_lock lock(accountA->getMutex(), accountB->getMutex());

        accountA->changeMoney(-amount);
        accountB->changeMoney(amount);
    }

    double totalMoney() const {
        double sum = 0;
        for (auto a : mAccounts) {
            sum += a->getMoney();
        }
        return sum;
    }

private:
    set<Account*> mAccounts;
};


"Also try to use a std::scoped_lock to lock both accounts’ mutexes when performing the transfer." I tried to do that, but it resulted in a deadlock.
